# why margin does not work in between div of 'bootstrap col'?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

http://bootply.com/84073

```
<div class"col-lg-12"="">
    <header class="clearfix">
        <section id="branding">
            <a href="index.php"><img src="https://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo4w.png" alt=""></a>
        </section>
  </header></div>
```

I tried to add #branding{margin: 0 auto} to style the logo to the middle, but it doesn't work

Comment: I can’t work unless you give the element a width – it is a block element, so per default it takes the whole available width.

Comment: That would center SECTION itself, but since it already fills the whole width, it doesn't do anything. You want to center the image inside the SECTION.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
 #branding{text-align: center;}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
img {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Should do the trick.