# center bootstraps nav items

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I add a new class to ul and try to style it with margin: 0 auto and text-align: center but doesn't work..

```
<section class="navbar navbar-default">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li class="active"><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="venue.php">Venue</a></li>
                <li><a href="schedule.php">Schedule</a></li>
                <li class="dropdown">
                    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Artists <span class="caret"></span></a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu">
                            <li><a href="artists.php" tabindex="-1">All Artists</a></li>
                            <li class="divider"></li>
                            <li><a href="#" tabindex="-1">1st</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#" tabindex="-1">2nd</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#" tabindex="-1">3rd</a></li>
                        </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="Register.php">Register</a></li>
            </ul>   
        </section>
```

Comment: Practically the same as your previous question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19091460/why-margin-does-not-work-in-between-div-of-bootstrap-col

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the fiddle with center bootstrap nav items...

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/etw66/2/)

You just need to add following css.

```
.navbar {
      text-align:center;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Like this

**[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/c5EuV/)**

**css**

```
.nav{
    background-color:red;
    width:300px;
    margin:0 auto;
    text-align:center;
}
.nav ul {
list-style-type:none;

}
.nav ul li{

}
```

Comment: you add just width or text-align:center; in your nav class from your bootstrap css